# Youtube Javascript API callback after pause

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api

I would like to display an image with a play button, as soon as someone clicks the image I create a youtube player play it. As soon as someone clicks on the "pause" button I would like to hide the player and show the image again.

Is there some kind of callback I can use? I tried to use the `onStateChange` callback

```
onStateChange: function (event) {
    if (event.data === 2) {
        // logic to hide it
    }
}
```

The problem is: this event is fired when someone changes the time as well, so as soon as a user left click the timeline the video signals to "pause" and becomes hidden. Can I somehow check if the video is just buffering/changing the position instead of pausing actively by a user?

Answer (score 0):

Hopeing this to work...

```
</script>

<div class="module module-home-video">
    <span class="module-strip">Latest Product Video</span>
    <div id="video"></div>
</div>



<script>
    var player, playing = false;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('video', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'RWeFOe2Cs4k',
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log(playing)
        if(!playing){
            alert('hi');
            playing = true;
        }else{
            playing = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And how would I check when the user pauses the video? I am not sure what to do with your code since it will only signal when the video starts the first time

Comment: Thank you for your help but I'm still not sure how this should help either... the callback is triggered whenever interactions with the player are done. Your current code will set `playing` to false when someone set a certain time. More importantly it will trigger several times at the beginning since multiple callbacks are fired. How am I supposed to know what causes the callback? I only want to receive an event when it is paused directly via "pause" button not via `setTime` event